# Serialising / Fetching Google Analytics Cookie data to webservice

Tags: serialization, cookies, google-analytics

I have a need to capture users on one website and pass them to a second website to complete a purchase and then send them back to the first website.

GA is enabled on the 2 separate sites, but there's no way to code server-side in either environment, but I do have access to the front-end code on both sites.

I want to capture the GA data from site 1 and apply it on site 2 to keep a consistent GA record of the user activity without site 2 treating site 1 as a referrer by reinitialising the cookie data in some way.

My current thinking is to employ a GET request to an iframe that's included on both sites and writing the GA code back to the browser so that it logs the pages in a more logically consistent fashion.

Google Search / Ad Word Click => Site 1 Basket => Site 2 (Record as Site 1) Purchase => Return to Site 1

Currently, Site 1 and Site 2 can't be integrated in a single flow within GA because the cookies for both domains are separate.

Any thoughts on the right logic would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the out-of-the-box cross-domain tracking functionality that comes with ga.js? The one where you have to set the _setAllowLinker flag, and push a _link on the outgoing link? ([this page has more info](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite)).

If that's not sufficient, the original urchin.js script had good cookie reading functionality you could reuse for a custom implementation.